# convert gstreamer pipeline to python code

Tags: python, gstreamer, nvidia, gobject

Im trying to convert gstreamer pipeline to python code using gi library.

This is the pipeline which is running successfully in terminal:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.0.150:554/H264?ch=1&subtype=0&proto=Onvif" latency=300 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder drop-frame-interval=1 ! nvvideoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,formate=I420 ! queue !  nveglglessink window-x=0 window-y=0 window-width=1080 window-height=720
```

but while running the same pipeline using python code, there is no output window displaying rtsp stream and also no error on the terminal. The terminal simply stuck until i press ctrl+c.

This is the code that im using to run the gstreamer command:

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst, GObject


def main(device):
    GObject.threads_init()
    Gst.init(None)

    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

    source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtspsrc", "video-source")
    source.set_property("location", device)
    source.set_property("latency", 300)
    pipeline.add(source)

    depay = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtph264depay", "depay")
    pipeline.add(depay)
    source.link(depay)

    parse = Gst.ElementFactory.make("h264parse", "parse")
    pipeline.add(parse)
    depay.link(parse)

    decoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvv4l2decoder", "decoder")
    decoder.set_property("drop-frame-interval", 2)
    pipeline.add(decoder)
    parse.link(decoder)

    convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nvvideoconvert", "convert")
    pipeline.add(convert)
    decoder.link(convert)

    caps = Gst.Caps.from_string("video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,formate=I420")
    filter = Gst.ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "filter")
    filter.set_property("caps", caps)
    pipeline.add(filter)
    convert.link(filter)

    queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make("queue", "queue")
    pipeline.add(queue)
    filter.link(queue)

    sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nveglglessink", "video-sink")
    sink.set_property("window-x", 0)
    sink.set_property("window-y", 0)
    sink.set_property("window-width", 1280)
    sink.set_property("window-height", 720)

    pipeline.add(sink)

    queue.link(sink)

    loop = GObject.MainLoop()

    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    try:
        loop.run()
    except:
        pass

    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.0.150:554/H264?ch=1&subtype=0&proto=Onvif")
```

Does anyone know what is the mistake? Thank you!

Comment: I have added the bus call definition in above code to capture the error. The error which im getting is "Error: gst-stream-error-quark: Internal data stream error. (1): gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:video-source/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc2:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because `rtspsrc`'s source pad is a so-called ["Sometimes pad"](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/advanced/request.html?gi-language=c#sometimes-pads). The link here explains it quite well, but basically you cannot know upfront how many pads will become available on the `rtspsrc`, since this depends on the SDP provided by the RTSP server.

As such, you should listen to the `"pad-added"` signal of the `rtspsrc`, where you can link the rest of your pipeline to the source pad that just showed up in the callback.

So summarised:

```
def main(device):
    GObject.threads_init()
    Gst.init(None)

    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
    source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtspsrc", "video-source")
    source.set_property("location", device)
    source.set_property("latency", 300)
    source.connect("pad-added", on_rtspsrc_pad_added)
    pipeline.add(source)

    # We will add/link the rest of the pipeline later
    loop = GObject.MainLoop()

    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    try:
        loop.run()
    except:
        pass

    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

def on_rtspsrc_pad_added(rtspsrc, pad, *user_data):
    # Create the rest of your pipeline here and link it 
    depay = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtph264depay", "depay")
    pipeline.add(depay)
    rtspsrc.link(depay)

    # and so on ....
```